# Python-social-auth: Redirect uri mismatch on Soundcloud login

Tags: python, django, soundcloud, python-social-auth

I'm having trouble associating Soundcloud accounts to user accounts on my app.

The app is built on django using python-social-auth, and I also have a Facebook association, which is working perfectly.

When I click on the soundcloud button, it redirects me to

http://local.gl.com:8080/?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirection+URI+provided+does+not+match+a+pre-registered+value.&state=OBclf3I3ODoKKD5uRdD97AozInK1iUF2#

and nothing happens.

local.gl.com is mapped to my development server address on /etc/hosts

my redirection URI on the soundcloud developers page is
http://local.gl.com:8080/ and on my `settings.py` I have:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL = '/users/register/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

On the .html file I have

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'soundcloud' %}?next={{ request.path }}"> soundcloud</a>
```

Which is basically the same thing I'm using for Facebook, which is working.

I've tried everything that I could find on SO, including registering a new app with soundcloud but I always get the same error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change the redirect URI on soundcloud page to

http://local.gl.com:8080/complete/soundcloud/

I had already tried that but I had a different error on the settings.py that I hadn't realised, so I was also getting an error with that uri